Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'AsyncDefaultValues' even I fill up all the form
I've been having a hard time why I get this warning when I tried to call a data from my database, I've been wondering where is the null | undefined when I'm hovering my defaultValues from react-hook-form down bellow

Type '{ id: string; title: string; email: string; fullName: string;
contactPerson: string; department: string; dateOfEvent: string;
startingTime: string; endingTime: string; purpose: string;
doesHaveDryRun: string; ... 11 more ...; updatedAt: Date; } | null |
undefined' is not assignable to type 'AsyncDefaultValues<{ title:
string; email: string; fullName: string; contactPerson: string;
department: string; dateOfEvent: string; startingTime: string;
endingTime: string; purpose: string; doesHaveDryRun: "yes" | "no"; ...
8 more ...; cameraSetup?: string | undefined; }> | { ...; } |
undefined'.   Type 'null' is not assignable to type
'AsyncDefaultValues<{ title: string; email: string; fullName: string;
contactPerson: string; department: string; dateOfEvent: string;
startingTime: string; endingTime: string; purpose: string;
doesHaveDryRun: "yes" | "no"; ... 8 more ...; cameraSetup?: string |
undefined; }> | { ...; } | undefined'.

this is my data coming from my database, As you can I see I fill up all inputs in my form, but I still get the warning above



id
title
email
fullName
contactPerson
department
dateOfEvent
startingTime
endingTime
purpose
doesHaveDryRun
dryRunDate
dryRunStart
dryRunEnd
doesHaveTCETAssitance
tcetOtherAssitance
meetingTypeOption
meetingTypeServices
meetingTypeServiceLink
cameraSetup
createdAt
updatedAt
status




clw4bmve20007o97k025zny6i
test6
test6@gmail.com
test6
test6
test6
5/14/2024
8:00 AM
12:00 PM
meeting
yes
5/15/2024
8:00 AM
10:00 AM
tcet,others
test6
meeting
meeting_attendees,meeting_waiting
sdsasd
twoCamera
2024-05-13 02:04:48.362
2024-05-13 02:04:48.362
PENDING



this is my zod schema
const formSchemaData = z.object({
    title: z.string().min(2, {
      message: "title must be at least 2 characters.",
    }),
    email: z.string().min(2, {
      message: "email must be at least 2 characters.",
    }).email(),
    fullName: z.string().min(2, {
      message: "The person who requested the event",
    }),
    contactPerson: z.string().min(2, {
      message: "Contact Person / Event Handler"
    }),
    department: z.string().min(2, {
      message: "department  must be at least 2 characters.",
    }),
    dateOfEvent: z.string(), // Assuming dateOfEvent is a string in the desired format
    startingTime: z.string().min(2, {
      message: "staring time must be set.",
    }),
    endingTime: z.string().min(2, {
      message: "ending time must be set.",
    }),
  
    purpose: z.string().min(2,{
      message: "Please choose a purpose of the meeting.",
    }),
  
    doesHaveDryRun:  z.enum(["yes", "no"], {
      required_error: "Please select if yes or not"
    }),
    dryRunDate: z.string().optional(),
    dryRunStart: z.string().optional(),
    dryRunEnd: z.string().optional(),

    doesHaveTCETAssitance: z.array(z.string()).refine((value) => value.some((item) => item), {
      message: 'Please select at lease on the option'
    }),
    tcetOtherAssitance: z.string().optional(),

    meetingTypeOption: z.enum(['meeting','webinar','hybrid','documentation', 'training']),
    meetingTypeServices: z.array(z.string()).refine((value) => value.some((item) => item), {
      message: 'Please select at lease on the option'
    }),
    meetingTypeServiceLink: z.string().optional(),
    cameraSetup: z.string().optional(),
   
    
  })

export type Events = z.infer<typeof formSchemaData>

And this is how I call the data from my database using tanstack query and set the initial value to my react-hook-form. Which will fill the data for my edit page
  const { id } = useParams();

  const { data: eventData, error, isFetching } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["id", id],
    queryFn: async () => {
      const res = await getDataById(id)
      return res
    },
  });

  const form = useForm<Events>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchemaData),
    defaultValues: eventData
  });




Since eventData is async and loads after the form is rendered, defaultValues will be undefined or null on initial render.  (whatever the initial value of data is before it is resolved) .
Updating defaultValues after initial render does not update the form.  You could add a useEffect to reset the form once the values are available.
useEffect(()=>{
  if(!eventData)return
  form.reset(eventData)
},[eventData])


is it a good approach even though I'm already using isFetching from tanstackquery?

isFetching could be used to show a loading state while the query is working, but it's not explicitly needed for the useEffect in my example.
